Job not recognized in different job dependsOn
I'm getting an error FinalJob Job depends on unknown TestJob job
azure-pipelines.yml
- ${{ if eq(parameters.FLAG, false) }}:
  - job: TestJob
    displayName: Testing job
    dependsOn: AnotherJob
    condition: succeeded()
    steps:
     - checkout: none

     - template: my-template.yml
       parameters:
        TARGET: ${{ parameters.TARGET }}

- ${{ if eq(parameters.FLAG, true) }}:
  - job: TestJob2
    displayName: Testing job 2
    dependsOn: AnotherJob
    condition: succeeded()
    steps:
     - checkout: none

     - template: my-template2.yml
       parameters:
        TARGET: ${{ parameters.TARGET }}


- job: FinalJob
  displayName: Final Job..
  dependsOn: 
  - TestJob
  - TestJob2
  condition: |
   or
    (
      eq(dependencies.TestJob.result, 'Succeeded'),
      eq(dependencies.TestJob2.result, 'Succeeded')
    )
  steps:
   - checkout: none

   - task: Bash@3
     displayName: 'Final script'
     inputs:
      targetType: 'filePath'
      filePath: './scripts/my-script.sh'

What I would like?
I'd like to call FinalJob if TestJob or TestJob2 work properly. How can i do that? is it not working because the if before TestJob and TestJob2?
What I tried?
I made it work but adding my parameters.FLAG as part of the job condition.. but it displays the job name in azure platform and I don't want that..

I can reproduce the same issue when using the YAML sample.

The cause of the issue is that the dependsOn field will read the job name at the compile time.
Since the if expression will let one of the job not be read at compile time, it will cause the unknown TestJob job issue.
To solve this issue, I suggest that you can set a variable in YAML Pipeline to determine which job to run and use it in dependsOn field.
For example:
parameters:
- name: FLAG
  type: string
  default: false


variables:
- ${{ if eq(parameters.FLAG, 'false') }}:
  - name: RunJob
    value: TestJob
- ${{ if eq(parameters.FLAG, 'true') }}:
  - name: RunJob
    value: TestJob2
jobs:
- job: AnotherJob
  steps: 
  - script:  echo "123"


- ${{ if eq(parameters.FLAG, false) }}:
  - job: TestJob
    displayName: Testing job
    dependsOn: AnotherJob
    condition: succeeded()
    steps:
     - checkout: none

     - template: my-template.yml
       parameters:
        TARGET: ${{ parameters.TARGET }}

- ${{ if eq(parameters.FLAG, true) }}:
  - job: TestJob2
    displayName: Testing job 2
    dependsOn: AnotherJob
    condition: succeeded()
    steps:
     - checkout: none

     - template: my-template2.yml
       parameters:
        TARGET: ${{ parameters.TARGET }}


- job: FinalJob
  displayName: Final Job..
  dependsOn: 
  -  ${{variables.RunJob}}
  condition: |
   or
    (
      eq(dependencies.TestJob.result, 'Succeeded'),
      eq(dependencies.TestJob2.result, 'Succeeded')
    )
  steps:
   - checkout: none

   - task: Bash@3
     displayName: 'Final script'
     inputs:
      targetType: 'filePath'
      filePath: './scripts/my-script.sh'

Result:



I'd like to call FinalJob if TestJob or TestJob2 work properly. How can i do that?

Two ways to get the goal, just simple-copy and try:
method1.yml
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

jobs:
- job: job1
  steps:
  - powershell: |
      Write-Output "hello from the job1"
- job: job2
  steps:
  - powershell: |
      Write-Output "echo hello from the job1"
      exit 1
- job: job3
  dependsOn:
  - job1
  - job2
  condition: or(succeeded('job1'), succeeded('job2'))
  steps:
  - powershell: |
      Write-Output "echo hello from the job3"

method2.yml
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

jobs:
- job: job1
  steps:
  - powershell: |
      Write-Output "your application steps in job1"
      Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=doThing;isOutput=true]Yes"
    name: job1var

- job: job2
  steps:
  - powershell: |
      Write-Output "your application steps in job2"
      exit 1
      Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=doThing;isOutput=true]Yes"
    name: job2var

- job: job3
  dependsOn:
  - job1
  - job2
  condition: or(eq(dependencies.job1.outputs['job1var.doThing'], 'Yes'), eq(dependencies.job2.outputs['job2var.doThing'], 'Yes'))
  steps:
  - powershell: |
      Write-Output "echo hello from the job3"

here using exit 1 to simulate the job failure.
